# Ошибка в описании знака "Любознательный"?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

У меня два вопроса, заданных вчера и пару недель назад, с положительным балансом голосов, НО они заданы никак не в пятидневный период. Это неправильное описание или ...?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ошибка перевода. Имеются в виду пять *разных* дней, а не обязательно пять дней подряд. [На английском так](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious):

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record.